# Windows Vista Boot mgr is missing after dual-booting with Fedora 14

Tags: windows, windows-vista, fedora, multi-boot, fedora-14

> Boot mgr is missing

This error is showing up when I choose Windows Vista (a.k.a. Other) from Grub after dual-booting with Fedora 14. How can I fix this problem if I don't have my Windows Vista installation/repair/recovery DVDs with me?

Here are the contents of my **/boot/grub/grub.conf**:

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,4)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
#          initrd /initrd-[generic-]version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,4)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora (2.6.35.6-48.fc14.i686.PAE)
        root (hd0,4)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.35.6-48.fc14.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.35.6-48.fc14.i686.PAE.img
title Fedora (2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686.PAE)
        root (hd0,4)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYTABLE=us rhgb quiet
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686.PAE.img
title Other
        rootnoverify (hd0,1)
        chainloader +1
```

**Update:** I already tried the [Vista Recovery Tool](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/download-windows-vista-x64-recovery-disc/) but it didn't solve the problem.Boot mgr is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by modifying this line from /boot/grub/grub.conf:

```
rootnoverify (hd0,1)
```

to

```
rootnoverify (hd0,2)
```

With the help of Fedora's Disk Utility, I noticed that the volume containing Windows Vista was in /dev/sda3 (hd0,2) and not /dev/sda2 (hd0,1).

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed Linux after windows, then the windows boot manager has been replaced by an open source one, typically GRUB. In my experience, the only way to fix this is to run a recovery using the windows install discs or if you can boot into windows, look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919529) for a solution, but it still requires the discs.